# Regarding Poission structure of Hamiltonian phase space

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

Why exactly do we need $$ \{q^i,p_j\}=\delta^i_j,$$  where $\delta^i_j$ is Kronecker delta and $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ is the Poisson bracket? What happens to the phase space structure if these fundamental relations are not satisfied, i.e. if $q$ and $p$ are dependent by some relation? What physical thing do these fundamental relations tell us about the Hamiltonian phase space?

Comment: *"Why exactly we need..."* We don't *need* it; it is just true by definition of the Poisson bracket: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket

Comment: For the classification of Poisson structures of the plane, check out appendix 14C of Arnold's *Mathematical Method for Classical Mechanics*

Answer (score 1):

Well, given an arbitrary $2n$-dimensional [symplectic manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) $(M,\{\cdot,\cdot\})$, the [Darboux theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem) shows that there locally always exist canonical coordinates $(q^1, \ldots, q^n,p_1, \ldots, p_n)$ satisfying
$$ \{q^i,p_j\}~=~\delta^i_j, \quad\{q^i,q^j\}~=~0, \quad\{p_i,p_j\}~=~0. $$