# Why do we need a Poisson bracket structure?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, constrained-dynamics, poisson-brackets

Let me start by asking why we need a Poisson bracket like structure on the Hamiltonian phase space? Say we have a constraint, why do we go through the trouble of defining a Dirac bracket structure on the phase space (which is a projection of PB structure) when we can just solve the EOM in normal algebraic terms and move on.

Comment: What is your "EOM in normal algebraic terms" if not $\dot{f} = \{H,f\}$? How do you formulate the Hamiltonian version of transformations being generated (like rotations by angular momentum) without a Poisson bracket?

Comment: we can just use the action principle to find EOM right? can you suggest some material where i can see more about the fundementals of PB @ACuriousMind

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/807206/2451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to motivate the Dirac bracket is to consider a situation where two second-class constraints $f_1,f_2$ have constant non-zero Poisson bracket $\{f_1,f_2\} = c \neq 0$, e.g. when we have a system where one pair of position and momentum is constrained as $p_1 = 0, q^1 = 0$.

Really, what we want in our theory is to be able to look at our equations "modulo constraints", i.e. impose $f_1 \approx 0,f_2 \approx 0$ and have everything be consistent. We cannot do this with the equation $\{f_1, f_2\} = c$, since plugging in the vanishing of the constraints yields $0 \approx c$, a contradiction. Hence the original Poisson bracket is not the right structure for this theory of constraints. If you are very straightforwardly only interested in solving equations of motion, you might not worry about this, but then again - if you are only interested in that, why are you doing the whole Hamiltonian formalism in the first place?

At the latest when we try to *quantize* this theory, we need a bracket that *does* play nice with the imposition of the constraints, since canonical quantization sends the bracket to the quantum commutator, and we cannot have states on which the constraint operators vanish but that also have $[f_1,f_2]\psi = c\psi$.

The Dirac bracket fulfills precisely this role since $[f_1,f_2]_\text{D} = 0$ by construction.

A purely classical way to motivate the Dirac bracket is geometrical: The constraints $f_i = 0$ pick out a submanifold $\Sigma = \{(q,p)\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}\mid f_i(q,p) = 0\}$ in phase space and we would like to consider this submanifold a phase space in its own right, "forgetting" that there was a larger space in which it is embedded. In order to do that, we cannot use the naive Poisson bracket of the embedding space, since as we saw above it can produce terms that you cannot possibly get from "inside" the submanifold where $f_i = 0$ always holds.

The [symplectic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) $\omega = \mathrm{d}q^i\wedge \mathrm{d}p^i$ underlying the Poisson bracket via
$$\{g_1,g_2\} = \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x^i}\omega_{ij}\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x^j} $$
induces a corresponding form on the submanifold in the standard sense: If $y^\lambda$ are coordinates of the submanifold and $x^i$ are the coordinates of ordinary phase space, then for the components $\omega_{ij}$ of the original form, the induced form has
$$ \omega_{\lambda\rho} = \omega_{ij}\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^\lambda}\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^\rho},$$
exactly like an induced metric would. When transformed back into the "bracket language", the induced bracket is
$$ [g_1,g_2]_\Sigma = \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y^\lambda}\omega_{\lambda\sigma}\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial y^\sigma},$$
and it turns out that $[-,-]_\Sigma = [-,-]_\mathrm{D}$, i.e. the induced bracket is the Dirac bracket, when all the constraints $f_i$ are second-class.

Comment: So the whole point of requiring a Poisson bracket like structure is for the purpose of quantization?